# Create tables by_group from list of vectors with inconsist lengths

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency

## Data:

- Each observation belongs to one of three groups; let's call them, "a", "b", and "c".
- Each observation consists of a vector of ids (integers). Many of the ids overlap, but many do not. There's easily over 1 million unique values, but it quickly becomes a more manageable # when I set a min freq around 10 or 20.
- Random data generated to resemble original data:

  ```
  set.seed(21) #GoSpursGo
  random_id <- function(n) sample(1111:11111, n, replace = TRUE)
  ids <- replicate(1000, random_id(sample(200:700, 400)))
  group <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
  df <- dplyr::data_frame(group = group, ids = ids)
  df

  ## Source: local data frame [1,000 x 2]
  ## 
  ## group         ids
  ## <chr>      <list>
  ## 1      b <int [593]>
  ## 2      a <int [444]>
  ## 3      b <int [605]>
  ## 4      b <int [263]>
  ## 5      a <int [274]>
  ## 6      c <int [450]>
  ## 7      c <int [656]>
  ## 8      b <int [687]>
  ## 9      a <int [302]>
  ## 10     a <int [234]>
  ## ..   ...         ...
  ```

## Objective:

- I want to create a table for each group which describes the frequency of, say, the top 1000 ids (across all groups).

## Problem:

- I can generate tables using base `lapply` and `table` functions, but they're slow, and it feels like I'm missing something obvious. Plus, I've got enough waves of the data that even small gains in efficiency make my life noticeably easier. I've only recently started using `dplyr` more [in place of base R functions], and the gains in efficiency have been excellent...but I'm drawing a blank [table] on this one.

## Question:

- Anyone have suggestions on how to efficiently create frequency tables derived from this kind of data structure? I'm, like, really into `dplyr` right now, so feedback in that direction would be cool, but I'd happily consider looking into other R packages if that's the case.

## Base R version:

```
## base R
base_tbl <- sapply(unique(df$group), function(x) 
  table(unlist(df$ids[df$group == x])))
  base_tb <- data.frame(
    ids = row.names(base_tbl), 
    base_tbl, 
    row.names = NULL,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(base_tb)
## ids  b  a  c
## 1 1111 21 19 16
## 2 1112 17 19 17
## 3 1113 15 16 12
## 4 1114 12 16 17
## 5 1115 10 14 17
## 6 1116  8 23 17
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Please show how you do it in base R so we know the expected result (even if it's slow)

Comment: Will post shortly as I just left my office.

Comment: Also, please add `set.seed`

Answer (score 1):

`tidyr` is helpful in the reshaping here. Since you don't really care about identifying which vector is which, first just `unnest` to long form, which you can pipe into `count` grouped by both columns, which is equivalent to `%>% table() %>% as_data_frame()` or `%>% group_by(group, ids) %>% summarise(n = n())`, collapsing duplicate observations of a `group`/`ids` combination to a single row, adding an `n` frequency column. `spread`ing to wide form lets you sort by the row sums of the counts, putting the most frequently occurring numbers at the top:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% unnest(ids) %>% 
  count(group, ids) %>% 
  spread(group, n) %>% 
  arrange(desc(rowSums(.[,-1])))

## # A tibble: 10,001 x 4
##      ids     a     b     c
##    <int> <int> <int> <int>
## 1  10162    22    24    26
## 2   8799    31    22    18
## 3   1173    27    25    18
## 4   2834    21    29    20
## 5   3957    24    27    19
## 6   4940    26    17    27
## 7   7757    23    19    27
## 8   5632    21    20    27
## 9   7565    24    24    20
## 10 10444    24    20    24
## # ... with 9,991 more rows
```

It runs effectively instantaneously on my machine despite 450k rows.